# CRON Scheduled WebJob abruptly quit being called

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have a WebJob scheduled to run every 10 minutes via Settings.job '0 0/10 * * *' that has been working fine then last night my job just quit being called. Looking around in eventlog.xml for the last call and I see the following

```
<EventData>
            <Data>7192</Data>
            <Data>LogCleanup</Data>
            <Data>Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE. hr: -2147024891</Data>
 </EventData>
```

No more calls after this, I manually run the job from the portal this morning and it worked fine and is being called eevery 10 minutes again as expected. My NLog internal log file logged the the following for the last run that was called

```
2016-12-15 21:40:02.6449 Error Error has been raised. Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation.Execute(CloudTableClient client, CloudTable table, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.Execute(TableOperation operation, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext)
   at NLog.AzureTableStorage.AzureTableStorageTarget.Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
   at NLog.Targets.Target.Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
Request Information
RequestID:1153c4ed-0002-000e-611b-57d353000000
RequestDate:Thu, 15 Dec 2016 21:40:02 GMT
StatusMessage:Conflict
ErrorCode:EntityAlreadyExists
```

The errors don't make any sense to me but the bigger question is why the job just quit being called? One run failed with some unexplained error and the scheduler quits calling it does not seem right.

How reliable are WebJobs? 
What kind of checks do I need in place to validate that they are being called?

Comment: After some more reading I wonder if this is may be the error that occurs by not having 'Always On' enabled for the hosting app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have **AlwaysOn** enabled for your Web App. CRON Scheduled jobs require this - see documentation [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#scheduling-a-triggered-webjob). The runtime will actually emit a Warning to the logs if we detect you don't have AlwaysOn enabled:

> Always On' doesn't appear to be enabled for this Web App. To ensure
>   your continuous job doesn't stop running when the SCM host is idle for
>   too long, consider enabling 'Always On' in the configuration settings
>   for your Web App. Note: 'Always On' is available only in Basic,
>   Standard and Premium modes.

Please check your [WebJob logs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#logging) for this - you should see it. The idea of that log was to help users auto-diagnose this, but perhaps you didn't see it? We also show a warning in the portal for the WebJob if we detect you have continuous WebJobs but AlwaysOn is not enabled. The warning for this will appear by the AlwaysOn setting on the settings page for your WebApp.

Comment: I show the logging I am aware of above, the new portal interface is so horrid where specifically do you find the logging you are mentioning?

Comment: The AlwaysOn warning I mentioned is written to the log files for your WebJob, the location of which are detailed [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs#logging) in our wiki. The portal based warning will show up by the AlwaysOn toggle in the Application Settings blade for your WebApp when we detect you have continuous WebJobs w/o this setting enabled. I think it might also show on the main WebJobs blade as well, I can't remember.

Comment: Are you implying that a cron scheduled webJob should be a specified as a continuous job? I have mine marked as 'OnDemand' in webjob-publish-settings.json.

Comment: OnDemand is correct, as per instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs#a-namecreatescheduledcronacreate-a-scheduled-webjob-using-a-cron-expression).

Comment: Ok, I don't have a continuous job so I guess there are no warnings that you mention. Maybe presence of a Settings.job file should also trigger the warning. Finally it does appear that the issue was not having Always On set to On. There may be specific warnings related to this for continuous webjobs but I see none for 'OnDemand' cron scheduled jobs in the portal or logs.

Comment: I never found the portal to provide any useful information related to this. The best indicator comes from the 'Missed XX schedules' entries you can find in the d:\home\data\jobs\triggered\jobName\job_scheduler.log. Interesting that it knows how many scheduled runs it misses after your site is no longer 'ON', Wonder why it can't turn on your site?

Comment: You are right that we don't emit this warning for cron triggered jobs, only continuous. I've logged an issue [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2282) in our repo to address that.